# What happens if Matter Reshaper reveals a land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When [Matter Reshaper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMatter%20Reshaper%5d) dies, it lets me reveal the top card of my deck. If it is a permanent with a converted mana cost of 3 or less, I put it onto the battlefield. If not, I put it into my hand. What happens if I reveal a land card? I assume it puts it onto the battlefield, but I just want to double check.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lands have a converted mana cost of 0, since that is equal to or less than 3 you are able to put it onto the battlefield.

> **202.3a** The converted mana cost of an object with no mana cost is 0, unless that object is the back face of a double-faced permanent or is a melded permanent.

Comment: As a note this land will not count as your land for the turn, since it was not 'Played' but instead put directly onto the battlefield.